Monitor problems with Framework Laptop 11th gen Intel with Plugable Thunderbolt dock
My new FL13 is proving unreliable at dealing with two large monitors connected to a Plugable dock via Thunderbolt. Symptoms:

sometimes the external monitors don't switch on (or show up in display settings) when connected to the dock
sometimes the laptop monitor won't switch on (or show up in display settings) when connected to the dock
machine hangs at boot-time with spinner going if dock connected

I have put an extract from dmesg in a pastebin. The end of the dmesg extract is when I disconnected and reconnected the thunderbolt cable between the laptop and the dock. I haven't yet turned off graphical boot to see what the error message is, but I will update this thread when I've done so.
[  482.677541] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  482.692432] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=2230, idProduct=2027, bcdDevice= 4.c4
[  482.692439] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  482.692441] usb 2-4: Product: USB3.1 Hub             
[  482.692443] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Plugable               
[  482.692444] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 000000001
[  482.693995] hub 2-4:1.0: USB hub found
[  482.694135] hub 2-4:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  482.766338] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[  482.766374] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[  482.766384] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[  482.766396] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
[  482.941325] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  482.974536] usb 2-4.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  483.015675] usb 2-4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0817, bcdDevice= 7.63
[  483.015679] usb 2-4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  483.015680] usb 2-4.2: Product: USB3.0 Hub             
[  483.015681] usb 2-4.2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  483.015682] usb 2-4.2: SerialNumber: 000000000
[  483.016980] hub 2-4.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  483.017122] hub 2-4.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  483.338310] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=2230, idProduct=2027, bcdDevice= 4.c4
[  483.338323] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  483.338326] usb 3-6: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[  483.338329] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: Plugable               
[  483.338332] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: 000000001
[  483.341572] hub 3-6:1.0: USB hub found
[  483.341815] hub 3-6:1.0: 6 ports detected
[  483.628393] usb 3-6.1: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  483.641943] usb 2-4.2.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  483.657937] usb 2-4.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0764, bcdDevice=29.59
[  483.657947] usb 2-4.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[  483.657951] usb 2-4.2.1: Product: USB Storage
[  483.657953] usb 2-4.2.1: Manufacturer: Generic
[  483.657956] usb 2-4.2.1: SerialNumber: 000000002959
[  483.658899] usb-storage 2-4.2.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  483.659107] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-4.2.1:1.0
[  483.725523] usb 2-4.2.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  483.739594] usb 2-4.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8156, bcdDevice=31.04
[  483.739605] usb 2-4.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[  483.739608] usb 2-4.2.2: Product: USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
[  483.739611] usb 2-4.2.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  483.739613] usb 2-4.2.2: SerialNumber: 4013000001
[  483.804420] usb 3-6.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=28c4, bcdDevice= 5.30
[  483.804431] usb 3-6.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  483.804434] usb 3-6.1: Product: FHD Camera Microphone
[  483.804437] usb 3-6.1: Manufacturer: SunplusIT Inc
[  483.804440] usb 3-6.1: SerialNumber: 01.00.00
[  483.805696] r8152-cfgselector 2-4.2.2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  483.819395] usb 3-6.1: Found UVC 1.00 device FHD Camera Microphone (1bcf:28c4)
[  483.842499] r8152 2-4.2.2:1.0: load rtl8156b-2 v3 10/20/23 successfully
[  483.875396] r8152 2-4.2.2:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
[  483.903207] r8152 2-4.2.2:1.0 enx8cae4cbd6b58: renamed from eth0
[  483.973535] usb 3-6.1: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x86
[  483.976055] usb 3-6.1: 3:2: cannot set freq 11025 to ep 0x86
[  484.039097] usb 3-6.1: 3:3: cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x86
[  484.169416] usb 3-6.1: 3:4: cannot get freq at ep 0x86
[  484.172143] usb 3-6.1: 3:5: cannot set freq 24000 to ep 0x86
[  484.235310] usb 3-6.1: 3:6: cannot set freq 32000 to ep 0x86
[  484.365413] usb 3-6.1: 3:7: cannot get freq at ep 0x86
[  484.474459] usb 3-6.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=3896), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  484.474468] usb 3-6.1: [7] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = 200/4096/1
[  484.552482] usb 3-6.2: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  484.643719] usb 3-6.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2817, bcdDevice= 7.63
[  484.643739] usb 3-6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  484.643740] usb 3-6.2: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[  484.643741] usb 3-6.2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  484.643742] usb 3-6.2: SerialNumber: 000000000
[  484.645897] hub 3-6.2:1.0: USB hub found
[  484.646074] hub 3-6.2:1.0: 5 ports detected
[  484.715262] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  MassStorageClass 2959 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  484.718162] scsi 0:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic  MassStorageClass 2959 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  484.718664] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  484.718962] sd 0:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  484.720093] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Media removed, stopped polling
[  484.720778] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  484.721697] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Media removed, stopped polling
[  484.722808] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  484.847388] usb 3-6.5: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  484.950639] usb 3-6.5: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[  484.954618] usb 3-6.5: New USB device found, idVendor=2230, idProduct=2028, bcdDevice=12.39
[  484.954634] usb 3-6.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  484.954635] usb 3-6.5: Product: FWupdater105Q6
[  484.954637] usb 3-6.5: Manufacturer: Plugable
[  484.954638] usb 3-6.5: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
[  485.030389] usb 3-6.6: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[  485.110008] usb 3-6.6: New USB device found, idVendor=2230, idProduct=2026, bcdDevice= 0.01
[  485.110018] usb 3-6.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  485.110022] usb 3-6.6: Product: UD-4VPD                
[  485.110024] usb 3-6.6: Manufacturer: Plugable               
[  485.110027] usb 3-6.6: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
[  485.358484] usb 3-6.2.3: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[  486.673170] wlp170s0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[  486.684324] wlp170s0: authenticate with c0:06:c3:31:2a:00 (local address=74:3a:f4:32:e1:0a)
[  486.686678] wlp170s0: send auth to c0:06:c3:31:2a:00 (try 1/3)
[  486.700070] r8152 2-4.2.2:1.0 enx8cae4cbd6b58: carrier on
[  486.718921] wlp170s0: authenticated
[  486.719402] wlp170s0: associate with c0:06:c3:31:2a:00 (try 1/3)
[  486.721467] wlp170s0: RX AssocResp from c0:06:c3:31:2a:00 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  486.748480] wlp170s0: associated
[  486.763581] usb 3-6.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=493b, bcdDevice= 0.04
[  486.763606] usb 3-6.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  486.763607] usb 3-6.2.3: Product: USB Audio
[  486.763611] usb 3-6.2.3: Manufacturer: Generic
[  487.366162] input: Generic USB Audio as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6.2/3-6.2.3/3-6.2.3:1.2/0003:0BDA:493B.0009/input/input36
[  487.417960] hid-generic 0003:0BDA:493B.0009: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Generic USB Audio] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.3/input2
[  487.534580] usb 3-6.2.4: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[  487.665757] usb 3-6.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c534, bcdDevice=29.00
[  487.665767] usb 3-6.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  487.665771] usb 3-6.2.4: Product: USB Receiver
[  487.665773] usb 3-6.2.4: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  487.674452] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.000A: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input0
[  487.729632] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.000B: hiddev0,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input1
[  487.784234] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.000B: device of type eQUAD nano Lite (0x0a) connected on slot 1
[  487.786108] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.000B: device of type eQUAD nano Lite (0x0a) connected on slot 2
[  487.792378] input: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6.2/3-6.2.4/3-6.2.4:1.1/0003:046D:C534.000B/0003:046D:4023.000C/input/input37
[  487.792814] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4023.000C: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input1:1
[  487.798202] input: Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4038 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6.2/3-6.2.4/3-6.2.4:1.1/0003:046D:C534.000B/0003:046D:4038.000D/input/input38
[  487.798465] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4038.000D: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4038] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input1:2
[  487.838981] thunderbolt 1-3: new device found, vendor=0x2230 device=0x2027
[  487.838990] thunderbolt 1-3: Plugable Plugable UD-4VPD
[  487.847438] usb 3-6.2.5: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[  487.926201] usb 3-6.2.5: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=8884, bcdDevice= 0.01
[  487.926212] usb 3-6.2.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  487.926215] usb 3-6.2.5: Product: USB Billboard Device   
[  487.926218] usb 3-6.2.5: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  487.926220] usb 3-6.2.5: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
[  491.148736] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in infoframes.enable (expected 0x00000000, found 0x00000004)
[  491.148751] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* mismatch in vsc dp sdp
[  491.148755] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* expected:
[  491.148758] i915 0000:00:02.0: DP SDP: VSC, revision 0, length 0
[  491.148761] i915 0000:00:02.0:     pixelformat: RGB
[  491.148764] i915 0000:00:02.0:     colorimetry: sRGB
[  491.148767] i915 0000:00:02.0:     bpc: 0
[  491.148769] i915 0000:00:02.0:     dynamic range: VESA range
[  491.148772] i915 0000:00:02.0:     content type: Not defined
[  491.148775] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* found:
[  491.148777] i915 0000:00:02.0: DP SDP: VSC, revision 4, length 14
[  491.148780] i915 0000:00:02.0:     pixelformat: RGB
[  491.148783] i915 0000:00:02.0:     colorimetry: sRGB
[  491.148785] i915 0000:00:02.0:     bpc: 0
[  491.148787] i915 0000:00:02.0:     dynamic range: VESA range
[  491.148790] i915 0000:00:02.0:     content type: Not defined
[  491.148793] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  491.148795] i915 0000:00:02.0: pipe state doesn't match!
[  491.148851] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1168 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_modeset_verify.c:223 verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.149188] Modules linked in: hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib snd_ump cdc_mbim cdc_wdm cdc_ncm cdc_ether usbnet r8152 uas usb_storage mii rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer ccm snd_hda_codec_hdmi xe snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic drm_gpuvm drm_exec gpu_sched drm_suballoc_helper drm_ttm_helper qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp intel_uncore_frequency intel_uncore_frequency_common snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi x86_pkg_temp_thermal soundwire_generic_allocation intel_powerclamp soundwire_bus coretemp snd_soc_core kvm_intel snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec irqbypass snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul btusb polyval_clmulni snd_hwdep polyval_generic btrtl
[  491.149276]  ghash_clmulni_intel iwlmvm snd_pcm sha256_ssse3 uvcvideo cmdlinepart btintel cros_usbpd_charger snd_seq_midi sha1_ssse3 cros_ec_sysfs cros_usbpd_logger cros_ec_chardev cros_usbpd_notify cros_ec_debugfs videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm mac80211 snd_seq_midi_event aesni_intel spi_nor uvc libarc4 crypto_simd videobuf2_memops btmtk i915 mei_hdcp mei_pxp snd_rawmidi videobuf2_v4l2 cros_ec_dev mtd cryptd bluetooth iwlwifi snd_seq videodev snd_seq_device snd_timer rapl processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy processor_thermal_device videobuf2_common cros_ec_lpcs hid_sensor_als processor_thermal_wt_hint ecdh_generic hid_sensor_trigger intel_rapl_msr cros_ec mc intel_cstate ecc cfg80211 industrialio_triggered_buffer drm_buddy snd wmi_bmof kfifo_buf ttm processor_thermal_rfim mei_me hid_sensor_iio_common processor_thermal_rapl spi_intel_pci intel_rapl_common i2c_i801 mei drm_display_helper industrialio spi_intel i2c_smbus soundcore processor_thermal_wt_req cec processor_thermal_power_floor rc_core igen6_edac
[  491.149373]  processor_thermal_mbox i2c_algo_bit intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone intel_pmc_core intel_vsec int3400_thermal acpi_pad pmt_telemetry pmt_class acpi_thermal_rel joydev input_leds mac_hid serio_raw msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore nfnetlink dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_hid hid_multitouch hid_generic nvme intel_lpss_pci intel_ish_ipc crc32_pclmul psmouse nvme_core ucsi_acpi intel_lpss thunderbolt i2c_hid_acpi video typec_ucsi idma64 xhci_pci intel_ishtp i2c_hid nvme_auth xhci_pci_renesas typec hid wmi pinctrl_tigerlake
[  491.149436] CPU: 1 PID: 1168 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[  491.149442] Hardware name: Framework Laptop/FRANBMCP0B, BIOS 03.20 06/03/2024
[  491.149444] RIP: 0010:verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.149788] Code: fc ff ff 49 8b 7f 08 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 75 03 48 8b 1f e8 36 a0 93 c9 48 89 da 48 c7 c7 e8 b4 4d c1 48 89 c6 e8 24 f1 ea c8 <0f> 0b e9 ff fd ff ff 49 8b 7f 08 4c 8b 47 50 4d 85 c0 75 03 4c 8b
[  491.149792] RSP: 0018:ffff9850039d7a68 EFLAGS: 00010246
[  491.149797] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8b6082894c20 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  491.149800] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  491.149803] RBP: ffff9850039d7ad8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  491.149805] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8b6087db4000
[  491.149808] R13: ffff8b60840242b0 R14: ffff8b608fb7c000 R15: ffff8b6084024000
[  491.149810] FS:  00007da052e37ac0(0000) GS:ffff8b6227880000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  491.149814] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  491.149817] CR2: 0000382811926e20 CR3: 0000000109bbe005 CR4: 0000000000f70ef0
[  491.149820] PKRU: 55555554
[  491.149822] Call Trace:
[  491.149825]  <TASK>
[  491.149830]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[  491.149838]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[  491.149849]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.150112]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[  491.150117]  ? handle_bug+0x51/0xa0
[  491.150121]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[  491.150124]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[  491.150129]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.150247]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.150350]  ? intel_connector_verify_state+0x53/0x360 [i915]
[  491.150440]  intel_modeset_verify_crtc+0x70/0xb0 [i915]
[  491.150538]  intel_atomic_commit_tail+0x685/0x9f0 [i915]
[  491.150648]  intel_atomic_commit+0x349/0x390 [i915]
[  491.150746]  drm_atomic_commit+0x96/0xd0
[  491.150749]  ? __pfx___drm_printfn_info+0x10/0x10
[  491.150752]  drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x82/0xd0
[  491.150754]  drm_mode_setcrtc+0x532/0x8b0
[  491.150757]  ? __pfx_drm_mode_setcrtc+0x10/0x10
[  491.150759]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xb9/0x120
[  491.150761]  drm_ioctl+0x2d4/0x550
[  491.150762]  ? __pfx_drm_mode_setcrtc+0x10/0x10
[  491.150765]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0xa0/0xf0
[  491.150767]  x64_sys_call+0x143b/0x25c0
[  491.150769]  do_syscall_64+0x7f/0x180
[  491.150771]  ? clear_bhb_loop+0x15/0x70
[  491.150773]  ? clear_bhb_loop+0x15/0x70
[  491.150775]  ? clear_bhb_loop+0x15/0x70
[  491.150777]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x78/0x80
[  491.150779] RIP: 0033:0x7da053124ded
[  491.150795] Code: 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 45 c8 31 c0 48 8d 45 10 c7 45 b0 10 00 00 00 48 89 45 b8 48 8d 45 d0 48 89 45 c0 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <89> c2 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 1a 48 8b 45 c8 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00 00
[  491.150796] RSP: 002b:00007ffe3eb51770 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[  491.150798] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00005febf4321b00 RCX: 00007da053124ded
[  491.150799] RDX: 00007ffe3eb51800 RSI: 00000000c06864a2 RDI: 0000000000000010
[  491.150800] RBP: 00007ffe3eb517c0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00005febf5b70f20
[  491.150800] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007ffe3eb51800
[  491.150801] R13: 00000000c06864a2 R14: 0000000000000010 R15: 00005febf41f4448
[  491.150802]  </TASK>
[  491.150803] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  491.247646] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in infoframes.enable (expected 0x00000000, found 0x00000004)
[  491.247662] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* mismatch in vsc dp sdp
[  491.247666] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* expected:
[  491.247669] i915 0000:00:02.0: DP SDP: VSC, revision 0, length 0
[  491.247673] i915 0000:00:02.0:     pixelformat: RGB
[  491.247676] i915 0000:00:02.0:     colorimetry: sRGB
[  491.247679] i915 0000:00:02.0:     bpc: 0
[  491.247681] i915 0000:00:02.0:     dynamic range: VESA range
[  491.247685] i915 0000:00:02.0:     content type: Not defined
[  491.247687] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* found:
[  491.247690] i915 0000:00:02.0: DP SDP: VSC, revision 4, length 14
[  491.247693] i915 0000:00:02.0:     pixelformat: RGB
[  491.247696] i915 0000:00:02.0:     colorimetry: sRGB
[  491.247699] i915 0000:00:02.0:     bpc: 0
[  491.247701] i915 0000:00:02.0:     dynamic range: VESA range
[  491.247704] i915 0000:00:02.0:     content type: Not defined
[  491.247708] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  491.247710] i915 0000:00:02.0: pipe state doesn't match!
[  491.247768] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 1168 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_modeset_verify.c:223 verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.248132] Modules linked in: hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib snd_ump cdc_mbim cdc_wdm cdc_ncm cdc_ether usbnet r8152 uas usb_storage mii rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer ccm snd_hda_codec_hdmi xe snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic drm_gpuvm drm_exec gpu_sched drm_suballoc_helper drm_ttm_helper qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp intel_uncore_frequency intel_uncore_frequency_common snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi x86_pkg_temp_thermal soundwire_generic_allocation intel_powerclamp soundwire_bus coretemp snd_soc_core kvm_intel snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec irqbypass snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul btusb polyval_clmulni snd_hwdep polyval_generic btrtl
[  491.248225]  ghash_clmulni_intel iwlmvm snd_pcm sha256_ssse3 uvcvideo cmdlinepart btintel cros_usbpd_charger snd_seq_midi sha1_ssse3 cros_ec_sysfs cros_usbpd_logger cros_ec_chardev cros_usbpd_notify cros_ec_debugfs videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm mac80211 snd_seq_midi_event aesni_intel spi_nor uvc libarc4 crypto_simd videobuf2_memops btmtk i915 mei_hdcp mei_pxp snd_rawmidi videobuf2_v4l2 cros_ec_dev mtd cryptd bluetooth iwlwifi snd_seq videodev snd_seq_device snd_timer rapl processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy processor_thermal_device videobuf2_common cros_ec_lpcs hid_sensor_als processor_thermal_wt_hint ecdh_generic hid_sensor_trigger intel_rapl_msr cros_ec mc intel_cstate ecc cfg80211 industrialio_triggered_buffer drm_buddy snd wmi_bmof kfifo_buf ttm processor_thermal_rfim mei_me hid_sensor_iio_common processor_thermal_rapl spi_intel_pci intel_rapl_common i2c_i801 mei drm_display_helper industrialio spi_intel i2c_smbus soundcore processor_thermal_wt_req cec processor_thermal_power_floor rc_core igen6_edac
[  491.248321]  processor_thermal_mbox i2c_algo_bit intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone intel_pmc_core intel_vsec int3400_thermal acpi_pad pmt_telemetry pmt_class acpi_thermal_rel joydev input_leds mac_hid serio_raw msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore nfnetlink dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_hid hid_multitouch hid_generic nvme intel_lpss_pci intel_ish_ipc crc32_pclmul psmouse nvme_core ucsi_acpi intel_lpss thunderbolt i2c_hid_acpi video typec_ucsi idma64 xhci_pci intel_ishtp i2c_hid nvme_auth xhci_pci_renesas typec hid wmi pinctrl_tigerlake
[  491.248392] CPU: 5 PID: 1168 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W          6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[  491.248397] Hardware name: Framework Laptop/FRANBMCP0B, BIOS 03.20 06/03/2024
[  491.248400] RIP: 0010:verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.248763] Code: fc ff ff 49 8b 7f 08 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 75 03 48 8b 1f e8 36 a0 93 c9 48 89 da 48 c7 c7 e8 b4 4d c1 48 89 c6 e8 24 f1 ea c8 <0f> 0b e9 ff fd ff ff 49 8b 7f 08 4c 8b 47 50 4d 85 c0 75 03 4c 8b
[  491.248768] RSP: 0018:ffff9850039d77e8 EFLAGS: 00010246
[  491.248773] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8b6082894c20 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  491.248776] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  491.248779] RBP: ffff9850039d7858 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  491.248782] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8b6081bc2000
[  491.248784] R13: ffff8b60840242b0 R14: ffff8b60d96aa000 R15: ffff8b6084024000
[  491.248788] FS:  00007da052e37ac0(0000) GS:ffff8b6227a80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  491.248792] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  491.248795] CR2: 0000735a4802c0f8 CR3: 0000000109bbe004 CR4: 0000000000f70ef0
[  491.248799] PKRU: 55555554
[  491.248801] Call Trace:
[  491.248805]  <TASK>
[  491.248810]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[  491.248819]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[  491.248829]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.249208]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[  491.249221]  ? handle_bug+0x51/0xa0
[  491.249231]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[  491.249239]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[  491.249253]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.249650]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x50c/0x690 [i915]
[  491.250057]  ? intel_connector_verify_state+0x53/0x360 [i915]
[  491.250418]  intel_modeset_verify_crtc+0x70/0xb0 [i915]
[  491.250746]  intel_atomic_commit_tail+0x685/0x9f0 [i915]
[  491.251101]  intel_atomic_commit+0x349/0x390 [i915]
[  491.251436]  drm_atomic_commit+0x96/0xd0
[  491.251444]  ? __pfx___drm_printfn_info+0x10/0x10
[  491.251454]  drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x82/0xd0
[  491.251463]  drm_mode_setcrtc+0x532/0x8b0
[  491.251484]  ? __pfx_drm_mode_setcrtc+0x10/0x10
[  491.251493]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xb9/0x120
[  491.251501]  drm_ioctl+0x2d4/0x550
[  491.251507]  ? __pfx_drm_mode_setcrtc+0x10/0x10
[  491.251514]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0xa0/0xf0
[  491.251525]  x64_sys_call+0x143b/0x25c0
[  491.251535]  do_syscall_64+0x7f/0x180
[  491.251545]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
[  491.251555]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[  491.251561]  ? do_iter_readv_writev+0x149/0x1d0
[  491.251573]  ? vfs_writev+0xe9/0x330
[  491.251587]  ? do_writev+0x108/0x170
[  491.251595]  ? do_writev+0x125/0x170
[  491.251605]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
[  491.251613]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[  491.251619]  ? clear_bhb_loop+0x15/0x70
[  491.251628]  ? clear_bhb_loop+0x15/0x70
[  491.251636]  ? clear_bhb_loop+0x15/0x70
[  491.251644]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x78/0x80
[  491.251650] RIP: 0033:0x7da053124ded
[  491.251695] Code: 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 45 c8 31 c0 48 8d 45 10 c7 45 b0 10 00 00 00 48 89 45 b8 48 8d 45 d0 48 89 45 c0 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <89> c2 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 1a 48 8b 45 c8 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00 00
[  491.251701] RSP: 002b:00007ffe3eb51770 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[  491.251709] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00005febf43235d0 RCX: 00007da053124ded
[  491.251712] RDX: 00007ffe3eb51800 RSI: 00000000c06864a2 RDI: 0000000000000010
[  491.251714] RBP: 00007ffe3eb517c0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00005febf4f379f0
[  491.251717] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007ffe3eb51800
[  491.251720] R13: 00000000c06864a2 R14: 0000000000000010 R15: 00005febf41f4448
[  491.251724]  </TASK>
[  491.251727] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  521.512287] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4038.000D: HID++ 2.0 device connected.
[  523.792224] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4023.000C: HID++ 2.0 device connected.


Disabling graphical boot at least stops the system from hanging at boot time. However it still seemingly won't detect all 3 screens. If anyone can help, I'd be most appreciative!
